# About ADC's 'No missing code'

Tags: adc

Some 16 bit ADC's specifications has "No missing code: 14 bits min", like ADI's [AD7656](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/AD7656_7657_7658.pdf). I want to know where the 14 bits locate in the 16 bits. Does it mean the high 14 bits?

According to the definition of 'No missing code', the missed code can be one or more of the possible 2^n binary code. Assume a 16 bit ADC with 1 bit missing code, no matter where the missed code locate, i can safely use it as a 15 bit ADC, right?

And i want to know the relation of DNL and 'No missing code', i think if a 16 bit ADC specified with DNL = +/-4 LSB, i can assume the no missing code is 14 bit, right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the high bits are the *only* ones that can be contiguous over the entire input range, this specification *must* refer to the high bits.

Answer (score 1):

No missing codes is about the error a conversion can make compared to other conversions around the same point.
These errors are small, so yes these errors are always about the LSB and therefor the 'No missing codes' about the MSB bits. DNL (Differential Non-Linearity) is about the maximum deviation between 2 adjacent steps, so basically the same as 'no missing codes'.
Another important factor is INL (Integral Non-Linearity), which is the error compared to  a straight line of conversion. So if the error is 10bit on a certain point (due to offset / deviation of reference or adjustment) you will know all values will be within 10bit+/-4bit.

Depending of the purpose of your design you have to either look at DNL or INL.
If it is about absolute values you have to look at INL since it can not be adjusted. So the best the converter will do for you is 16bit minus INL (if offset and absolute error is calibrated). If it is only about difference you can mostly ignore INL and just look at DNL/'No missing codes'.

Comment: While a missing code will contribute to increasing the DNL, even with no missing codes you still have DNL, even in an ideal ADC.  DNL is not "basically" equal to 'no missing codes'

Comment: A DNL is an absolute count, so DNL is more precise and 1bit DNL will not be reflected in missing codes. But else I would be interested in what fundamental difference you see?

Comment: No, DNL is not an absolute count. With a ADC without missing codes, the DNL is usually a measure of differences in step size (Voltage wise) from one count value to another.  Perhaps from varying thresholds or switch points.  In data-sheets the DNL value is the average value over all values, i.e a 1 sigma estimate of it's probability density.  DNL plots with voltage sweep are usually very complex but will always manifest the sawtooth residual error.

Comment: With absolute count I meant the bitcount representing the voltage error. I would say it is not possible for a 16 bit converter with 16bit 'no missing codes' to have an DNL of 2 (or the voltage representing 2LSB)? What's new for me is the average error part,are you sure about this? Like the errors on the positive side would be able to compensate for the errors on the negative side?!

Comment: 110% sure, a DNL plot is very complex, the DNL specification in the data-sheet is a measure of the whole DNL plot expressed in one number.  You can't expect the DNL to be constant for every output value.

Comment: ok, I thought it was the max value (within a certain probability). Never too late to learn :)

Comment: Wikipedia however explains DNL however exactly like I understood it. For now I'll just note that my knowledge on this might not be accurate and next time at work when I need this I'll dive into this a bit more.

Comment: The Wiki article describes what DNL is for an individual step.  Ask your self how this gets distilled to a single number over the range of the conversion.

Comment: I agree with placehoder. The DNL specification usually is a maximum value, and is a estimate of probability density.

Comment: Still not sure about average maximum value, except to be more precise than the converter actually is (DNL=0.41LSB). I read no additional probability in the definition from AD: Differential linearity error is defined as the maximum amount of deviation of any quantum (or LSB change) in the entire transfer function from its ideal size of 1 LSB.
According to p2.17 of http://www.analog.com/library/analogDialogue/archives/39-06/Chapter%202%20Sampled%20Data%20Systems%20F.pdf
Maybe we mean the same but there is a translation problem, I do fully agree with the mentioned definition in the paper.

Comment: @Requis: The definition of DNL is accurate, but the 'test procedure' usually complicated, please check this link: http://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/2085